# Woocommerce cart page adding extra <p> tags

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

The cart page for woocommerce is generating a ton of extra p tags. Does anyone have a solution to this or know why this is happening? I've disabled the auto p in wordpress and it still doesn't solve the issue.

I saw this same question was asked on here in January but there was no solution mentioned.
 Link: [Woocommerce cart adding extra <p> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269033/woocommerce-cart-adding-extra-p-tags)

Example:

```
<form method="post" action="http://toughguppyproductions.com/traceymallett/cart/">
<p></p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<table class="shop_table cart" cellspacing="0">
</form>
```

Comment: What method did you use to remove `wpautop`?  Even if you removed it from `the_content` filter, it's possible WC applies it manually to their own filter somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The only item in the source code between the `form` and the `table` tags is this:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>
```

I couldn't find anything in WooCommerce itself which hooked into this action, but you could try searching for the action name `woocommerce_before_cart_table` through your theme and plugin code and see if you can find what is being added.